# Yii2 - How to make a sum of my column in GridView?

Tags: gridview, yii2, sum

How do I sum up the values of a column in my GridView and display the total?

My GridView:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
'query' => Accounts::find()->where('account_type=1'),
'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['account_code'=>SORT_ASC]],
]);
echo GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'account_code',
        'account_name',
        'amount',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
```

[My table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMjvW.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit better and dynamic way :

1) create function in model

```
public static function getTotal($provider, $columnName)
{
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($provider as $item) {
      $total += $item[$columnName];
  }
  return $total;  
}
```

2) View

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'showFooter' => true,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'account_code',
        'account_name',
        [
         'attribute' =>'amount',
         'footer' => ModelName::getTotal($dataProvider->models, 'amount'),
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ] 
]) ?>
```

Comment: Same way, I tried it as a header and it worked as per my expectation. thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

To calculate the amount for all pages, make some changes to your code:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Accounts::find()->where('account_type=1'),
    'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['account_code'=>SORT_ASC]],
]);
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'showFooter' => true,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'account_code',
        'account_name',
        [
            'attribute' =>'amount',
            'footer' => $dataProvider->query->sum('amount'),
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ] 
]);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could add  some code for calculate the total

This kind of operation should be done   in you controller  (or you could add  a proper function in model)

In you case you are working directly in view (is not a good practice, but anyway) yo

```
  $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
  'query' => Accounts::find()->where('account_type=1'),
  'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['account_code'=>SORT_ASC]],
  ]);

   // calculate the result in $mySum
   foreach ($provider as $item) {
          $mySum += $item['amount'];

      }

  // add showfooter => true,
  echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'showFooter' => true,
    'columns' => [
          ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
          'account_code',
          'account_name',
          [
           'attribute' =>'amount',
           'footer' => $mySum, // add the footer values
          ],
          ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
  ],
  ......
```